# TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'merge' call

Tags: spring, spring-boot, entitymanager, jpa

We have some old spring applications where we have little bit spring-boot annotations. I have a scenario where I want to perform merge using EntityManager, but this is throwing "javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'merge' call" exception. I have tried solutions available in other post such as using javax.persistent @Trasactional annotations on the upload() method level, but nothing worked. These are the classes I am using -

**ApplicationContextProvider.java**

```
@Service
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private static ApplicationContext context;

  public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return context;
  }

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException {
    context = ac;
  }
}
```

**MyConfigType.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "config_loaded_table")
public class MyConfigType { 
  @Id
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "file_name")
  private String fileName;  

    // getters and setters
}
```

**ConfigUploader.java (abstract class)-**

```
public abstract class ConfigUploader {
    public abstract String upload() throws Exception;
}
```

**ConfigLoader implementation class where I am using merge from entityManager-**

```
public class MyConfigLoader extends ConfigUploader {

    private int id;
    private String path;

    public MyConfigLoader(int id, String path) {
        this.id= id;
        this.path=path;
    }

    @Override
    public String upload() throws Exception {

        try {
            MyConfigType myConfigType = new MyConfigType();
            myConfigType.setFileName("employee.config");

            // at this line I am getting exception. 
            int id = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(EntityManager.class).merge(myConfigType).getId();
            myConfigType.setId(id);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // getting javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'merge' call
           log.error(e); 
        }
    }
}
```

**And finally, the main class where I am calling upload() method of ConfigLoader implementation-**

```
public class ConfigThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        ConfigUploader configLoader = new MyConfigLoader(id,path);
        configLoader.upload(); // calling upload() method here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetly, your class is not a spring component, so @Transactional can not be used here. You can try something like this:

```
EntityManager entityManager = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(EntityManager.class);
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.merge(...);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: This is throwing "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead"

Comment: So to make it work I had to first get the bean of entityManagerFactory and then create entityManager from it. i.e.  EntityManagerFactory  entityManagerFactory = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(EntityManagerFactory.class); EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();